# Is it possible to see the code generated by Macwire

Tags: playframework-2.6, silhouette, macwire

Is it possible to see what is the code generated by `wire` macro

```
lazy val securedRequestHandler : SecuredRequestHandler = wire[DefaultSecuredRequestHandler]
```

In the above example, I want to know what arguments were passed when `DefaultSecuredRequestHandler` was created. `DefaultSecuredRequestHandler` is not my class. It is part of `Silhouette` library.

I am trying to create an instance of `DefaultSecuredRequestHandler` and I need to pass `BodyParser.Default` to it but I dont know from where to get it. However, I found some code online which us using Macwire to create instance of `DefaultSecuredRequestHandler`. Thus I want to know how `DefaultSecuredRequestHandler` was created.

```
new DefaultSecuredAction(requestHandler: SecuredRequestHandler, bodyParser: Default) //I don't know how to create a bodyParser of type Default
```